# How can I generate an image based on text and CSS?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a web app. It generates signatures for a game, with information from its API.

I'll need to store the images with a script that gathers the information and turns it into an image.

Do you know a way to turn text + CSS into an image?

Comment: I think this will need to be done via some server side code.

Comment: Read up on using HTML Canvas. You can write text into to and then grab it as an image. I don't think you'll find one answer on StackOverflow that does all of these things, but here's a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786836/how-to-add-text-into-canvas

Comment: Might want to try a JavaScript library to make it a pdf.

Comment: @edhedges Maybe 5 years ago. Now we have the `<canvas>` element

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes this can be done, what you want to do is draw the text on a canvas, and then save the canvas.  you do not need to have the canvas show, you can hide it like any other html element, just add it, draw the text on it, and save it.

Here is a link on a library that saves:
https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image

Some sample code drawing text on canvas:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Your Text",10,50);

// save img
Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(c, 200, 100, 'png');
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know any free(it can be small) database?so I can save the images?  
it will be like this:  
http://www.host.com/generator.html/NAMEHERE
  
  So every link that someone joins with its name in the link as showed,will generate an image?

Comment: You mean, to store the images on your server, or to store them somewhere else?  You could build the image each time the url is requested.  That might be best, since then its always client side, and you have very little bandwith.

Comment: Yeah,thats what I want.How do I do that?

Comment: the code above will actually do that.  Are you trying to return an image, or html?

Comment: How does one actually save the image to your local disk? Like so that the image appears in the same folder...