# Convert contents of a div to an image with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For a little project I'm working on, I create a div with some other div's inside (and possibly more element types in the future). I want the user to be able to click a button to download an image representation of the div.

As a side note, I'd like this project to be pure javascript/css/html (so no jQuery or others).

Here's is an example piece of code:

```
<div>
    <div style="background-color: #80ceed;">Test Text</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if there is no way to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate an image based on text and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618574/how-can-i-generate-an-image-based-on-text-and-css)

Comment: When you say "image representation of the div", what kind of content are we talking about in the div? Because this question could go from real easy to real freaking hard depending on your scope considering you don't want any external libraries.

Comment: I mean a something like a screenshot of everything inside the div

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely do it with canvas. unfortunaly I don't know canvas so i can't provide you the code but someone alredy did what you want to do here https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: I found this, and it seems great. Problem is that it requires jQuery (as far as I know, the documentation is rather minimal). I try to avoid using jQuery and other libraries as much as possible to keep the total size small, and to try to get the most out of JS itself.

Comment: it does not require jquery here a made an example for you
[link] (https://paste.ofcode.org/zBC3Xz5HLa9ys5DNrg6xtG)